# Why is this code returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why is this function returning undefined? Result obviously has a non-null value and the call is entering the first if statement as it prints the desired output.

```js
function Swap(str, result) {
    if (str == "") {
      console.log(result); 
      return result;
    }
    else if (str[0] == str.toUpperCase().substring(0,1)) {
      var newResult = result + str.toLowerCase().substring(0,1);
      Swap(str.replace(str[0], ""), newResult);
    }
    else {
      var newResult = result + str.toUpperCase().substring(0,1);
      Swap(str.replace(str[0], ""), newResult);
    }
   }

console.log(Swap("HelloW",""));
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you want to use `str.slice(1)` instead of `str.replace(…)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `Swap("HelloW", "")` will enter the second `if` case (`str` starts with an uppercase), which invokes `Swap("elloW", "h")` and *doesn't return anything*. You need `return` on the other two branches too, not just on the first one.